# Xamarin with UWP - "FileNotFound_AssemblyNotFound, ClrCompression"

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.ios, .net-native

I develop UWP application using [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin). I have a compilation problem with `.NET` native tool chain. When I check the flag `"Compile with .NET Native tool chain"`, I get an error in runtime on `"Xamarin.Init"` method:

> "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: FileNotFound_AssemblyNotFound, ClrCompression.
>   For more information, visit
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485"

And the next one:

> "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: FileNotFound_AssemblyNotFound, sqlite3. For
>   more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485"

I added `SqLite` assembly, according to advice from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Dependency_Services_and_.NET_Native_Compilation)

```
List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();
var assembly = typeof(SQLitePlatformWinRT).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
assembliesToInclude.Add(assembly);
//throws error there
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
```

My references:

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I work at Microsoft and would love to help. Can you send your project.json and project.lock.json files to us? dotnetnative@microsoft.com.

Comment: Any outcome on this? I have the same problem with my Xamarin.Uwp project and can't solve it.

Comment: @Tom see my answer below and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The solution was added assemblies from my solution.
You have to add **all of** the assemblies from solution.
See this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Target_Invocation_Exception_when_using_Compile_with_.NET_Native_tool_chain):

Try add assemblies from solution.

```
    List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();
    assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(<a class from assembly>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
```

Comment: I know that Xamarin-article, but I was not succesful up to now. I have several references, also pcl which also have references. So I don't know, which assemblies to add to this list. Can you pls post your code with your assemblies list?